# Miraclecast on 16.04

Tags: wireless, display, wifi-direct

I'm trying to install Miraclecast on 16.04, but the installation isn't working (I barely know where to start). Somebody can explain how I could install Miraclecast?

This is the error:

```
./autogen.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

Comment: What have you tried? Be specific. if you've used commands then edit your question with commands you used

Comment: I enter this site: "https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast"
There I downloaded the file called "autogen.sh", saved in the / tmp folder. I opened Konsole in this folder and reading "readme.md" I used the ./autogen.sh command.
Both root and normal user the error message is this:

ricardo@ricardo-Aspire-E1-431:~$ sudo ./autogen.sh
[sudo] senha para ricardo: 
./autogen.sh: 8: ./autogen.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected

Answer (score 1):

You should have systemd version >= 219 to build this.
To check version of systemd, run `systemd --version`.

1. Go to https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast.
2. Download the entire source code, not just `autogen.sh`. You can do it by clicking the *Clone or download* button, and  then *Download as ZIP* or directly at https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/archive/master.zip.
3. Unzip the folder to get folder `miraclecast-master` and run:

   ```
   cd miraclecast-master
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools autoconf libtool libudev-dev libsystemd-dev glib-2.0 libperl-dev libgtk2.0-dev libreadline-dev
   libtoolize; aclocal; autoconf
   sudo ./autogen.sh
   ```
4. Once `./autogen.sh` is complete, run:

   ```
   sudo ./configure
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: I got an error (autoreconf not found) with './autogen.sh' and had to first do 'sudo apt-get install -y autoconf' to run the install. Still cannot get it to cast to the TV-Miracast dongle -- yet.

Comment: Can you tell me where are you stuck now?

Comment: It is not showing up on the TV yet, it seems to be connecting as the dongle LED flickers then goes solid. This is a dual boot with win8.1 and Miracast works when I boot to win so I know the dongle is OK. But Ubuntu is my main OS and do not want to have to drop back to win8 just to watch videos on the big screen. I plan on getting a projector and using an older laptop on our network (with Ubuntu of course), so need to get this to work with this laptop as I know it does OK with win. Then install Miraclecast on the old laptop.

Comment: https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues/4