# How can i connect ubuntu 17.10 to my LG Smart TV

Tags: internet, tv

I installed ubuntu 17.10 normally and just want to duplicate my screen on my LG Smart TV, i have normal wifi but Miraclecast doesnt work for me and the intel WiDi thingy for linux is just code and i cant do anything with that. please help!

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking for: 1) a wireless solution; 2) a wireless solution that doesn't include Miracast or WiDi, or 3) any solution? If Option 3, I'd recommend a HDMI cable between computer and TV: pretty much guaranteed to work.

Comment: 2 because it is very expensive to buy a dongle and i am not going to sit 2 cm off my screen.... windows can do this so why cant linux?

Comment: You mention that you were able to connect to your LG Smart TV using Windows. How are you doing this? Perhaps that will help us better understand your issue.

Comment: action menu > connect tv (miracast)

Comment: @richbl Windows 10 has this by default in screen settings for Intel graphics.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments, it sounds like you're using Miracast under Windows, the successor being Miraclecast. I'd recommend downloading and installing the [Miraclecast project](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast). The quick procedure would be to:

- Download the [zip file from the release folder](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/releases)
- In  the `miraclecast-1.0` folder, run the `autogen.sh` script
- Run `./configure`
- Run `make`
- Finally, run `sudo make install`

This should install Miraclecast on your machine.

For a discussion and additional details, see the [detailed AskUbuntu thread here](https://askubuntu.com/a/973758/32664).

Comment: Offhand, I'd guess that you don't have the proper dependencies installed on your machine. I'd recommend that [you work with the project developer and community](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues) who can help you troubleshoot specific issues directly.

Comment: For me it is not easy to compile this, I could not make it. But I did find PPA's in Ubuntu, so things worked to install. I think I connected to my TV, but the problem is to send stream to TV, did not find an easy solution for that (if any).

Comment: Is Miraclecast project still working? I was able to install it, but I don't know how to use it (as there is not interface/extra button)..