# Cannot connect to wireless projector (Samsung LED TV)

Tags: wireless, projector, smart-tv

I installed Ubuntu on my new laptop and I need to connect it to a Samsung LED TV.

When I was in Windows 10 I was able to connect to my TV by just pressing the combination of <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Then it would automatically connect to it. I can't connect now.

- Dell Inspiron 15 3552
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the wireless projection You will need miraclecast to cast your screen over using the [wireless display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiDi) technology. To install miracle cast in Ubuntu via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/miraclecast
sudo apt update
sudo apt install miraclecast ubuntu-restricted-extras check
```

If the `apt update` fails, it might be because currently, this ppa has no Releases file. With current versions of apt, this blocks the `apt update` because the ppa is not secure enough. To sidestep this, we can disable this check for this repo. This is an insecure thing to do. Bad actors with access to the PPA could publish malicious code there without having access to the release file signing key. Try at your own risk:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thopiekar-ubuntu-miraclecast-disco.list
```

To the first line of this file, add the `[allow-insecure=yes]` part:

```
deb [allow-insecure=yes] http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/miraclecast/ubuntu disco main
```

Save the file, try the steps above again, from 'sudo apt update'.

**To start casting**

1. Shutdown `wpa_supplicant` and NetworkManager:

   ```
   sudo killall wpa_supplicant && sudo service network-manager stop
   ```
2. Launch wifi daemon:

   ```
   sudo miracle-wifid &
   ```

   Now run miraclecast as a peer (peer is your device that is casting its screen to the TV):
3. Launch wifi control:

   ```
   sudo miracle-wifictl
   ```

   this should give you the miraclecast CLI and a link number. select the link with `select link`
4. Enable wifi-direct visibility on the other device (if possible)
5. From the CLI locate the TV using:

   ```
   p2p-scan
   ```

   you get something like

   ```
   12:34:ab:cd:45:43.
   ```

   ie the mac address

   Then from the CLI initiate connection:

   ```
   connect <mac addr> [pin]
   ```

   the pin could be the pin of the tv

Also look at the answers to [How can i connect ubuntu 17.10 to my LG Smart TV](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989016/how-can-i-connect-ubuntu-17-10-to-my-lg-smart-tv)

The miraclecast project page is also [here on GitHub](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast).

Comment: i got a connection but i can't see my screen on the TV. can you please help

Comment: its is supposed to cast automatically once you connect.  open an [issue here](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues). the developer assist you to solve it

Comment: `ppa:thopiekar/miraclecast` does not have a Release file, which prevents the `apt update`.

Comment: I added an edit suggesting what to do if `apt update` fails...

Comment: After adding 'allow-insecure=yes' to the ppa, it still doesn't work for me. `apt update` eventually concludes `E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/miraclecast/ubuntu/dists/disco/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]`

Comment: The above is because the ppa has no packages built for 19.04 (disco).

Answer (score 0):

If you can update to Ubuntu 21.04, there's Gnome-network-displays (available through the Flatpak system) which works reasonably well.